# Is there a way to disable the regex expression highlight in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, settings

Is there a way to disable the regex expression highlight in Intellij?

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may disable default injection settings for Kotlin in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections - "Kotlin - RegExp" "